# How to disable pytest xdist only when pytest is called with filters?

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist

When I run all pytests I do want to fully benefit from spreading the load on all m cores (xdist) but when I run a subset of them is almost always for development/debugging purposes, case in which I do want to avoid the downsides of xdist as:

- slower start time
- unable to use pdb debugging

To examplify: calling `pytest -k foo` should effectively run `pytest -n0 -k foo`. Keep in mind that calling pytest without arguments should not affect the -n value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [dynamically add the option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/simple.html#dynamically-adding-command-line-options), for example:

*conftest.py*

```py
import sys

def pytest_cmdline_preparse(args):
    if "xdist" in sys.modules and "-k" in args:
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            # remove -n # option
            if arg == "-n":
                del args[i]
                del args[i]
                break
            # remove -n# option
            if re.match(r"-n\d+", arg):
                del args[i]
                break

        args[:] = ["-n0"] + args
```

This removes an existing "-n" option (both of the form `-n #` and `-n#` - you may not need both, depending on how your command line looks), and adds the "-n0" option instead.

*Update*:
`pytest_cmdline_preparse` is deprecated in current (6.x) pytest versions, `pytest_load_initial_conftests` can be used instead in the same manner.

Comment: A big Thanks!!! I did really worked. It may look weird but I think it was the reliable way of doing it for pytest,